# MongoDB project extra field in array

Tags: mongodb

I'll start off by saying that I have zero experience with MongoDB. I'm experienced with SQL and relational databases, but this whole MongoDB thing is completely new to me. We need to use it for a school assignment, though, but I simply cannot figure this out.

I have a document collection called "quests", which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("563b59f8da33f3593f29a3c6"),
    "questid" : 1,
    "userid" : "BillKellock@excite.us",
    "cache" : {
        "cacheid" : 1,
        "latitude" : 50.8921231431384200,
        "longitude" : 4.4543394886210281
    },
    "measurements" : [ 
        {
            "timestamp" : "2015-11-05T14:21:55.0980113+01:00",
            "heartrate" : 70,
            "pressure" : 1026,
            "temperature" : null,
            "conductivity" : 3371,
            "latitude" : 50.4533254161725400,
            "longitude" : 4.1293538055053700
        }, 
        {
            "timestamp" : "2015-11-05T14:21:55.0990122+01:00",
            "heartrate" : null,
            "pressure" : 947,
            "temperature" : 277,
            "conductivity" : 3918,
            "latitude" : 50.9827324962163000,
            "longitude" : 4.7924412785994086
        },
        ...
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("563b59f8da33f3593f29a3ce"),
    "questid" : 2,
    ...
```

What I need to do, is to get an overview of measurements grouped/ordered by cacheid and questid. The assignment is not very clear in this regard, I don't know whether I need to group them or just order them. Anyways, I tried grouping the measurements by cacheid, and then wanted to add the questid to the measurements so I can sort based on that field.

The query I have constructed so far is this:

```
db.quests.aggregate(
    [
        { $unwind: "$measurements" },
        { $group:
          {
                _id:"$cache.cacheid",
                measurements: { $push: "$measurements" }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: 
          {
                "measurements.timestamp": 1,
                "measurements.heartrate": 1,
                "measurements.pressure": 1,
                "measurements.temperature": 1,
                "measurements.conductivity": 1,
                "measurements.latitude": 1,
                "measurements.longitude": 1,
                "measurements.questid": "$questid",
          }
        }
    ]
)
```

This gives me measurements grouped by cacheid (which is shown as _id). However, there's no sign of the questid in the measurements array. I have no idea how to "add" the field there, and extensive googling did not help me further.

I did find .group() but that does not work on sharded collections (the collection I'm using is sharded)

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aggregation is wrong on the `$group` pipeline stage. The group stage assembles new documents based on your rules, and then pass them to the next stage. You only define the `_id` and measurements; that's why you cannot access `questid` on the projection stage.

You must add logic to deal with and even possibly add `questid` on the group stage. Then, you can use it on the projection stage.

Regarding your assignment, I think you are supposed to group and then sort the documents **using cacheid and questid as a compound key**. Something like this in your group stage:

```
'_id': {cacheid: '$cache.cacheid', questid: '$questid'}
```

Comment: Thank you! Making the id a compound key removes the need for adding the questid to the measurements.